# SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) - Replacing Select Statements with Stored Procedures or Table Valued Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I am considering replacing select statements with stored procedures or Table Valued Functions.

Currently, data source has huge select statements. I think that using stored procedures or table valued functions could bring following benefits:

1. Easy to maintain & manage code.
2. Code can be shared among teams (developers/testers/analysts)
3. Performance could benefit from stored execution plans.
4. Packages could be maintained without opening BIDS/data tools.

When is it a good practice to replace **select** queries with stored procedures or table valued functions?

In general, SELECT queries are 100+ rows long using CAST, ISNULL, CASE, REPLACE, COALESCE and joining other 4 tables

Comment: Why would you have huge select statements as your data source in the first place? Is it something that cannot be achieved in SSIS? Can you share an example?

Comment: A huge select statement is even huger when represented with all the various joins, orders, lookups etc. in SSIS.

Comment: @godzilla2014 - I guess SSIS could achieve the requirements; however, I prefer to do any data conversions, data manipulation, derived columns purely in T-SQL and ussing SSIS for data movement from A to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually considered to be a good practice to use stored procedure in place of lengthy SELECT statement in the OLEDB Data source. There are few other disadvantage as well:

1. The SQL query editor in the OLEDB source has a limitation in parsing the query if it is too long or complex with many variables.
2. Limitation on number of variables (specially on large). For example: a 200+ line query gets parsed properly with 2 variables, but if you introduce one more variable - it stops working

I had the connect bug references somewhere but they weren't fixed and the workaround is provided by using stored procedure or table valued function.

In short: **If the SELECT statement is big/complex/changeable - use stored procedure **

--
While the question is valid in nature - usually this type of open question are discouraged in Stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

Why hasn't anyone mentioned a `VIEW` yet? Just push your select statements into a database view. Then when there is a change you don't have to open up your package you can just change your view.

Only use stored procedures or table valued functions if you have some procedural logic required.

Answer (score 0):

When any SQL statement is executed in SQL Server, the relational engine first looks through the procedure cache to verify that an existing execution plan for the same SQL statement exists. SQL Server reuses any existing plan it finds, saving the overhead of recompiling the SQL statement. If no existing execution plan exists, SQL Server generates a new execution plan for the query.

Using Stored procedures increase the chances of execution plan re usability.